# How to create a table using dynamic columns chosen from a slicer to power a visual? - PowerBI

Tags: dynamic, charts, powerbi, dax, slicers

I am trying to show summarized/aggregated data visually for products that have similar values for multiple user selected columns.

An example of the data (actual data has approximately 300 unique columns for entire product catalog):
[image: Example Data]

Essentially I am trying to get to an end result resembling this visual:
[image: Desired Result]

Where you can select the columns via the slicer on the left and see summarized data for products grouped by values from the selected columns.

I tried to make a summarized table using dynamic columns from the slicer like so:
[image: Desired Dynamic Table]

Using the following DAX:

```
SUMMARIZE (
    'ProductData',
    'ProductData'[fuel_type_label_id],
    'ProductData'[configuration_label_id],
    "Values",
        CONCATENATE (
            'ProductData'[fuel_type_label_id],
            " + " & 'ProductData'[configuration_label_id]
        ),
    "Total Items", COUNT ( 'ProductData'[item_id] ),
    "Total Revenue", SUM ( 'ProductData'[Revenue] )
)
```

However, I could not figure out how to make the GroupBy Column 1 & 2 dynamic to the slicer in the SUMMARIZE function, which I'm not even sure is possible.

**Is it possible to pass the SUMMARIZE function dynamic columns from a slicer or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?**

Comment: Can you share your pbix file ?

Answer (score 0):

The `SUMMARIZE` function doesn't provide a native way to dynamically choose the columns based on a slicer or another user input. However, you can create a more dynamic behavior like below :

Create a measure that will return the desired value based on the selected slicer option. You can use the `SWITCH` function to return different results based on a slicer value.

Then use this measures inside the `SUMMARIZE` function to dynamically change the grouping and aggregation based on the slicer's selection.

```
GroupByColumn1 = 
SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE( 'SlicerTable'[GroupByOption1] ),
    "Option1", 'ProductData'[fuel_type_label_id],
    "Option2", 'ProductData'[configuration_label_id]
    // Add more options as needed
)

GroupByColumn2 = 
SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE( 'SlicerTable'[GroupByOption2] ),
    "Option1", 'ProductData'[fuel_type_label_id],
    "Option2", 'ProductData'[configuration_label_id]
    // Add more options as needed
)

DynamicSummarize = 
SUMMARIZE (
    'ProductData',
    [GroupByColumn1],
    [GroupByColumn2],
    "Values",
        CONCATENATE (
            [GroupByColumn1],
            " + " & [GroupByColumn2]
        ),
    "Total Items", COUNT ( 'ProductData'[item_id] ),
    "Total Revenue", SUM ( 'ProductData'[Revenue] )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to get your solution to work. 
Here is a link to the pbix with the sample data above if you would like to look at it:
https://mega.nz/file/tmFkEbhJ#2fXJvWciJpXbhAKOHtA21QWivtdU8K-zm3xwHW1pfLg

Comment: After checking  your file unfortunately, there is no simple way to use a slicer to dynamically change the columns you're grouping by in a SUMMARIZE function. You'll likely need to find a way to work around this limitation by creating different measures for each of the combinations of categories you might want to summarize by.